# Highcharts series gap auto zipping

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am having an issue with the gap between separated series of highcharts.

For example, I have a chart with two series. One starts from (1st March 2004) and the other starts from (1st March 2009). They do not overlap each others. When showing on the chart, the barchart automatically zips the time between two chart (skipping the year 2005, 2006...2008) and display 2 time series closing to each others.

[image: autozippingtime]

Please refer to this for more detail:
https://jsfiddle.net/quangvinh910/6vr6dg15/2/

```
pointStart: Date.UTC(2004, 3, 1),

pointStart: Date.UTC(2009, 3, 1)
```

How can I show show the full time range between that on the x-axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highstock automatically will try and strip out the gaps in the data so that there is not lots of "dead" space. This is done with the option [`xAxis.ordinal`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal):

> In an ordinal axis, the points are equally spaced in the chart
>   regardless of the actual time or x distance between them. This means
>   that missing data for nights or weekends will not take up space in the
>   chart. Defaults to true.

It is true by default. Try setting it to `false`. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/6vr6dg15/5/).